# Do "types" of predictions "need" to match assumptions about data?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, uncertainty, probabilistic-forecasts

Let $\mathcal X$ (observation space) and $\mathcal P$ (prediction space) be non-empty sets.

Let $P$ be a variadic function (predictive model) mapping tuples of elements of $\mathcal X$ into $\mathcal P$.

Let $\ell: \mathcal X \times \mathcal P \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a loss function.

The predictive task is then defined as follows:

1. $x_0$ is generated by some unknown mechanism, $M$.
2. We observe $x_0$.
3. We generate a prediction, $p_1 = P(x_0)$.
4. $M$ generates $x_1$.
5. We observe $x_1$ and $\ell(p_1, x_1)$.
6. We generate a  prediction, $p_2 = P(x_0, x_1)$.
7. We observe $x_2$ and $\ell (p_2, x_2)$.
8. and so on...

with the goal being to minimize some cumulative function of the losses.

Given this situation, is there any natural structure (point, probabilistic, etc.) that we can put onto $\mathcal P$ in terms of $\mathcal X$ that doesn't "mislead" us, but will still allow us to make more "holistic" predictions that convey potential uncertainty, etc. than just letting $\mathcal P := \mathcal X$ ?

I know that "all models are wrong...", but is there any underlying danger in using a prediction space that "makes" further assumptions about the data? such as letting $\mathcal P$ be a set of probabilistic predictions over $\mathcal X$ when we initially made no assumptions about how $x_0, x_1, \dots$ were generated (e.g. they could be deterministically, adversarially, or otherwise-generated).

I'm aware that the study of "prediction of individual sequences" does address some of  this, but from what I've
seen, there isn't too much on how to choose $\mathcal P$ or otherwise create a model $P$ that doesn't rely on weighting/considering the input of "experts" (other predictive models).

**An example would be as follows:**

Let $\mathcal X := \{0, 1\}$.

We don't make any assumption on how the $x_0, x_1, \dots \in \mathcal X$ are generated. They could be deterministically, probabilistically, adversarially (say w.r.t to our previous predictions), or otherwise-generated.

Is it then a violation of our assumptions (or lack thereof) to use a predictive model that maps into a prediction space $\mathcal P \neq \mathcal X$? such as letting $\mathcal P$ be the set of all Bernoulli distributions and $P$ be the function mapping the tuple of elements in $\mathcal X$ to the empirical PMF of the elements of the tuple (fraction of 0's and fraction of 1's).

**Hopefully more succinctly:**
Does making a probabilistic (or other type of) prediction for a data point assume that that data point was/will be generated probabilistically (or otherwise)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean something like how a linear probability model allows for nonsense predicted probabilities like $2$ and $-1$, but that we can bound those by applying a link function (e.g., logistic regression)?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, @Dave! and not exactly, I don't think, I added an example that should hopefully clarify what I'm trying to ask, let me know if I didn't convey it clearly enough. :)